# Cant get variables from other file

Tags: php

i have got this code in my connect.php

```
  $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['firstname']=$firstname;
```

And this in my Main.php

```
$_SESSION['firstname']=$firstname;
echo $firstname;
```

But it gives me this error Undefined variable: firstname in

Comment: It's because in Main.php `$firstname` is undefined.

Comment: @Daan How can it be defined?

Comment: Main.php is back to front: `$firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];`

Comment: Though you will need to call `session_start()` in order to use sessions, as pointed out in the answer

Comment: Did you try setting a session variable directly in connect.php, eg `$_SESSION['firstname']='testingsessions';` to rule out an issue with POST? Also, you should have error reporting on, you would likely see your issues

Comment: @steve Yes i have done that and there was nothing on the screen

Comment: No errors when you turned on error reporting??

Comment: Have you tried `include 'path/to/file';`, that brings the variable into scope of the document (as long as you use the variable after the include)

Comment: @Steve Well now i have changed some things and it shows it.But i have deleted header so i cannot header user.

Comment: What did you change? Care to add as an answer so the community can use this too?

Comment: @SamSwift Yes o have include connect.php

Comment: Then surely all you need to do is submit the post and ten everything will be there?

Comment: `"But i have deleted header so i cannot header user"` Please clarify what this means, it doesnt make much sense

Comment: @SamSwift But i did not get what i want

Comment: try `if ($_POST) { var_dump($_POST); } print '<br />'; var_dump($GLOBALS);` at *the bottom* of your script or just before where the error is thrown and see what's held in them

Comment: @Steve I used header to redirect user from registration page.But now i have deleted that.I want user to be redirected from registration page and get all values of inputs that he filled.

Comment: If you can, please also add the result from the `var_dump`s on your question to aid in getting an answer

Comment: It gave me long text.@SamSwift

Comment: @J.doe This has become an odd guessing game. Please edit your question to include the actual code - it is pointless going backwards and forwards in comments like this

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *long text*, this may very well be the difference between an answer and a failed script for you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your connect you should have something like

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];
```

and in Main.php

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['firstname'];
```

Comment: I cant have session_starts in any of files it gives me this error     session_start();

Comment: You must have it.. it must be called in each file where you want to use session variables. Please note that if you include the files you must open the session only in the parent file right after the php tag

Comment: yes i have opened it in parent so i don't open it again.I checked your code it is not giving me any errors but it is not showing anything.

Comment: maybe because `$_POST['firstname']` is not holding anything? recheck your form input name to be sure it is correct

Comment: I header user from one page to main.php where there is input with name="firstname" so i guess it holds

Comment: check if the form method is set to `POST`